# How to set scale type of a ImageView such that image should be center crop and upper part is always visible

Tags: android, imageview

In my project there are multiple images in the news feed. I want that image inside ImageView should be displayed in a way that it should be center crop as well as upper part of the image is always visible.

You can refer for the below screenshots where in image1 the image is displayed using center crop and upper part of the image is not visible:

[image]

And the image2 which displayed the image in center crop as well as the upper part of the image is also visible:

[image]

I want 2nd image type of ImageView.
If anyone can help me here then please provide the solutions. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, they really need just a scale type of "fit" or "crop" and then a gravity: "center", "top", "start", etc.  But for now we have to do it like this:

First, set your `ImageView` to scale by matrix:

```
    <ImageView
        ...
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

Then you have to do it in code:

```
    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
```

...

```
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    // Using the view tree observer to make sure the ImageView 
    // is laid out so we have a valid width and height.
    // You don't have to do this if you know your ImageView is already
    // laid out when the image bitmap is fetched.
    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            // I had a preset bitmap on the view so I used this
            // Just get the actual dimensions of the bitmap
            float iw = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
            float ih = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

            // Get the dimensions of the view
            float vw = imageView.getWidth();
            float vh = imageView.getHeight();

            // Compute the scale factors
            float scaleW = vw / iw;
            float scaleH = vh / ih;

            // For a crop, we take the largest scale factor
            float scale = Math.max(scaleW, scaleH);

            // First, center the image horizontally
            mMatrix.setTranslate((vw - iw) / 2, 0);

            // Then scale the image from horizontal center & vertical top
            mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale, vw / 2, 0);

            imageView.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
        }
    });
```